# Asp.net - Postback loses Dropdownlist index

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a simple Dropdownlist control that JS handles,
once the index changes, a div is opened/closed.

html code for initializing the Dropdownlist-

```
    <select id="selectmethod" onchange="run()">
      <option value="1" selected="selected">option1</option>
      <option value="2" >option2</option>
    </select>
```

JavaScript code to handle OnChange event-

```
       function run() {
            var e = document.getElementById("selectmethod");
            var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

            if (value == 1) {

                $('#changecourseitems').slideUp();
                $('#addnewcourseitems').slideDown();
            }
            if (value == 2) {

                $('#addnewcourseitems').slideUp();
                $('#changecourseitems').slideDown();

            }
```

Now when the user clicks on an `<ASP:LinkButton ... />`
a Postback event starts and the Dropdownlist index resets (so as the hidden div).
How can I maintain the Dropdownlist index after the Postback ?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to maintain the Dropdownlist index? Usually, ASP.NET will take care of that. If you want to your open / closed div to maintain their state, that's another question.

Comment: Well I described it in the post, but ASP.NET does not take care of the dropdownlist index because it resets everytime I click the Linkbutton

Comment: Do you have something in the codebehind that sets the index of the dropdownlist?

Comment: @jokesonhiltionhotel you got a problem my friend since your select control it's not a asp control, why you dont use a asp control dropdownlist ? it would be much more simple

Comment: If you are not using a update panel , every post back the entire page it's render again

Comment: @LucasRoselli I am using an update panel and I tried using the builtin asp dropdownlist control and it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: I don't wanna sound rude, but are you sure that you use it right ? And all the answers bellow , it worked ? And did you check the ClientIDMode="Static" wich I mencioned in my answer ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/32741607/3202657 if you didn't put this attribute, your js file will not find the control

Comment: But I'm pretty sure that with all the answers you got it now

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the contents of the dropdownlist you either have to re-populate it on the server every time or use viewstate. For example you can populate the data once like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "option1", Value = "1", Selected = true });
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem() { Text = "option2", Value = "2" });
    }
}
```

and in the page you can use an ASP control and enable view state:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Now the data will be posted back and forth and will be maintained on the client side

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the value, there are multiple approaches.
1.  Change the select to server control.
2.  Add a hidden value and save your select tag value to this hidden value in your run().  And then set the select value 
    in document.ready().

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="yourHiddenValue" runat="server" />
```

Your run method.

```
function run() {
    var e = document.getElementById("selectmethod");
    var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if (value == 1) {

        $('#changecourseitems').slideUp();
        $('#addnewcourseitems').slideDown();
    }
    if (value == 2) {

        $('#addnewcourseitems').slideUp();
        $('#changecourseitems').slideDown();

    }

    $('#<%=yourHiddenValue.ClientID%>').val(value);  // <--- added
}
```

This is document ready function.

```
$(function() {
    var hiddenValue = $('#<%=yourHiddenValue.ClientID%>').val();
    $('#selectmethod').val(hiddenValue);
}
```

Comment: But the div 'changecourseitems' keep closing everytime I click the linkbutton, I want it to stay open as it is should be opened in index 2 at the list.

Comment: u probably need to apply the logic (show/hide) in the document ready function

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the control's state in ASP.Net Web Form, you want to use **DropDownList Server Control** which uses **ViewState** under the hood.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownList1">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Add New Course" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Change Course" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>

<div id="changecourseitems">Change course</div>
<div id="addnewcourseitems">Add new course</div>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="Server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" 
    Text="Submit" />

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var selectMethod = function(){
            if ($('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').val() === '1') {
                $('#changecourseitems').hide();
                $('#addnewcourseitems').slideDown();
            } else {
                $('#addnewcourseitems').hide();
                $('#changecourseitems').slideDown();
            }
        }
        $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(selectMethod);
        selectMethod();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I tried exactly how you mentioned, and it is maintaining the list index, but it's still closes the div that should've been opened while index is 2 (for instance). I want it to maintain the index but also maintain the div visible.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="selectmethod" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

With the ClientIDMode=static you maintain the id as it is specify on the control

your js file should be:

```
  $('#selectmethod').change(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();

     if (value == 1) {

        $('#changecourseitems').slideUp();
        $('#addnewcourseitems').slideDown();
     }
     if (value == 2) {

        $('#addnewcourseitems').slideUp();
        $('#changecourseitems').slideDown();

     }
  });
```